# Why isn't my axios call return a response?

Tags: node.js, axios, microservices

In the following segment of code, I place a call to a microservice using axios.

```
app.get('/api/user/microservice/signin', async (req, res) => {
    console.log('USER SIGNIN BEGINS')
    try {
        const user = await axios.post('http://localhost:4210/usermicroservice/signin', req.body)

        console.log('USER CONTROLLER user from mongo ', user)
        res.send(user);
    } catch (error) {
        throw error;
    }
});
```

The target function is invoked, the data is retrieved from the database but the result never gets to the calling function. They system just hangs.

The called function:

```
app.post('/usermicroservice/signin', async (req, res) => {
    console.log('\n*** USER MICROSERVICE SIGNIN CALLED ***')

    let user = await UserMicroservice.signin(res, req.body);   
    console.log('user from mongo ', user)      
    // res.status(200).json({user})
    return user;
});
```

UserMicrosevice.signin() returned value:

```
if (await PasswordUtil.check(user.password, existingUser.password) == true) {
        existingUser.token = PasswordUtil.generateAccessToken(existingUser, user.password);
        console.log('existingUser token', existingUser.token)
        console.log('existingUser', existingUser)
        delete existingUser.password;
        let credentials = { name: existingUser.name, email: existingUser.email, token: existingUser.token };
        return credentials;
    }
```

CORS:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    next();
})
```

Comment: Does the DevTools emit some errors? Can you place a breakpoint after the user is retrieved and see what happens next?

Comment: after the user is retrieved, I log the result to the console. It it looks fine. then I return user.

Comment: `Axios` returns the value in a very specific way, the `Response` object should have a `data` prop, inside that property should be the result you want. I see you commented out the response from your microservice as a JSON, what was the problem there?

Comment: res.json(user) sends the result to postman, not to the calling function.

Comment: Sure, I understand, but since you're calling an `endpoint` from your app, you should return the value as a `JSON` or something that meet your needs, in my opinion.

Comment: user is returned from  UserMicroservice.signin() as a JSON object.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192131/discussion-between-sigfried-and-koque).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a while we figured it out, the microservice response should be:

```
app.post('/usermicroservice/signin', async (req, res) => {
    console.log('\n*** USER MICROSERVICE SIGNIN CALLED ***')

    let user = await UserMicroservice.signin(res, req.body);   
    console.log('user from mongo ', user)      
    res.status(200).json({user})
});
```